# Multiple condition When statement in Big Cartel

Tags: bigcartel

I am trying to make a multiple condition statement on Big Cartel and I keep getting an error telling me that there is an unknown tag in my When statement. I feel like this is very simple. What am I doing wrong? Thank you for looking.

```
{% case product.status %}

{% when 'sold-out' %}
{% if product.id = '25027747' %}
RESULT 1
{% else %}
{% if product.id = '25027993' %}
RESULT 2
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use this code:

```
{% case product.status %}
  {% when 'sold-out' %}
    {% if product.id = '25027747' %}
      RESULT 1
    {% elsif product.id = '25027993' %}
      RESULT 2
    {% endif %}
{% endcase %}
```